# Interpreting networkQuality JSON output

Tags: network, command-line

If you run `networkQuality -c` you get a nice JSON output suitable for later processing. The problem I have is that I can speculate but I am not sure about what every key and the unit for its value is in the output.

Here is sample output of `networkQuality -c` below, except I deleted the contents of the arrays for brevity:

```
    {
      "base_rtt" : 42,
      "dl_flows" : 20,
      "dl_throughput" : 278482080,
      "end_date" : "12/29/22, 6:27:55 PM",
      "il_h2_req_resp" : [],
      "il_tcp_handshake_443" : [],
      "il_tls_handshake" : [],
      "interface_name" : "en0",
      "lud_foreign_h2_req_resp" : [],
      "lud_foreign_tcp_handshake_443" : [],
      "lud_foreign_tls_handshake" : [],
      "lud_self_h2_req_resp" : [],
      "os_version" : "Version 13.1 (Build 22C65)",
      "responsiveness" : 75,
      "start_date" : "12/29/22, 6:27:38 PM",
      "ul_flows" : 20,
      "ul_throughput" : 15571602
    }
```

Many are self-explanatory. But some aren't. What is the meaning of each and what unit is used? I could not find documentation and the man page was of no help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to the overview is not working, but I found `man networkQuality`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/347527)

Comment: The networkQuality man page in macOS 14.4 does appear to provide the requested information. For example, in the section "Computer Output Field Description" we have:

base_rtt      The calculated idle latency of the test run (in milliseconds).
dl_flows      Number of download flows initiated.
dl_responsiveness      The downlink responsiveness score (in RPM)
...

where the meaning of each key and the units are given.

Comment: When I wrote the question, the man page didn't have the info. Looks like it does now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a good overview: https://danpetrov.xyz/macos/2021/11/14/analysing-network-quality-macos.html

> Upload/download capacity (your Tx/Rx bandwidth essentially)
> Upload/download flows, this seems to be the number of test packets
> used for the responsiveness tests Upload/download responsiveness
> measured in Roundtrips Per Minute (RPM), which according to Apple, is
> the number of sequential round-trips, or transactions, a network can
> do in one minute under normal working conditions

Comment: Considering you commented on the Reddit thread where I found that link, I'm guessing you have already seen the contents of my link :-D

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete list, will edit if comments fill in any blanks.

- `base_rtt`: ❓
- `dl_flows`: ❓
- `dl_throughput`: Download speed in bits per second. Divide by 1 million to get Mbps.
- `end_date`: Local time of when the test ended running.
- `il_h2_req_resp`: ❓
- `il_tcp_handshake_443`: ❓
- `il_tls_handshake`: ❓
- `interface_name`: Network interface the test ran on (e.g. en0 for WiFi on modern Macs).
- `lud_foreign_h2_req_resp`: ❓
- `lud_foreign_tcp_handshake_443`: ❓
- `lud_foreign_tls_handshake`: ❓
- `lud_self_h2_req_resp`: ❓
- `os_version`: macOS version test ran on.
- `responsiveness`: Round trips per minute. Higher is better.
- `start_date`: Local time of when the test started running.
- `ul_flows`: ❓
- `ul_throughput`: Upload speed in bits per second. Divide by 1 million to get Mbps.